# Newest Visualstudio cannot find .net Core packages

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I installed the new 2017 RC update and now anything is flooded in red...

I also reinstalled 2017, but nothing has changed, it still says

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    WebApplication3 c:\users\dominic.hueckmann\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Startup.cs 1   Active

I have the newest .net Core 1.0.0-rc3-004530

(sidenote maybe VS members read this : I miss the global.json, project.json times)

Comment: Did you get Build 26127.00 released Jan 27?  According to the release notes the implemented a number of .NET Core bug fixes:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

Comment: After that build I have these errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer I had to remove serveral things in the .csproj, just copy paste it from a new Project in 2017